# Rewrite rule / specialisation type error with universally quantified constraints

Tags: haskell, ghc, typeclass, haskell-lens

I am trying to implement some type-specific specialisations
of some functions that work with Prisms, and I am having difficulty with
GHC 8.  (I encounter a different problem with GHC < 8, but that's
for another question).

A (contrived) minimal example of the problem:

```
foo :: Prism' s a -> Prism' s a
foo = id

{-# RULES "foo/foo'" foo = foo' #-}
foo' :: Prism' Char Bool -> Prism' Char Bool
foo' = id
```

This causes the compiler error:

```
error:
• Couldn't match type ‘p0 Bool (f0 Bool) -> p0 Char (f0 Char)’
                 with ‘forall (p :: * -> * -> *) (f :: * -> *).
                       (Choice p, Applicative f) =>
                       p Bool (f Bool) -> p Char (f Char)’
  Expected type: Prism' Char Bool
    Actual type: p0 Bool (f0 Bool) -> p0 Char (f0 Char)
• In the expression: foo'
  When checking the transformation rule "foo/foo'"
```

It looks to me like one side of the rewrite rule type checking
"forgets" its context.  What is really going on here, and how
can I make GHC happy?

Comment: The example is a bit too contrived, I suspect. Can you come up with a minimal useful example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is in essence the old problem that rank-N types don't make a proper hierarchy of which type is more and which is less general. It seems like this specific case *could* be resolvable, but it's certainly not possible to write rewrite rules for general rank-N functions.

Fortunately, this is not much of an issue for lenses and friends, because these have always a monomorphic version available!

```
foo₀ :: APrism' s a -> APrism' s a
foo₀ = id

{-# RULES "foo/foo'" foo₀ = foo' #-}
foo' :: APrism' Char Bool -> APrism' Char Bool
foo' = id

foo :: Prism' s a -> Prism' s a
foo p = clonePrism $ foo₀ (clonePrism p)
```

Comment: Working only with `APrism` will miss a lot, won't it?

Comment: Could you explain this RankN hierarchy issue?

Comment: `APrism` is fully equivalent to (law-obeying) `Prism`, so, no, this won't miss anything. As for the RankN hierarchy, well... the essential problem is that, if you make a rank-N-1 argument of a function less polymorphic, the whole function type gets more polymorphic. It's not _that_ much of a problem, but you can't do type inference everywhere anymore. Haskell's rank-N types are already quite an amazing extension over the standard Damas-Milner inference, but I reckon some parts of the compiler, like rewrite rules can't fully make use of this. Not sure if this would theoretically work.

Comment: I don't see how that feature of higher-rank types would cause a problem for rules. I don't have my computer on me, but I wonder if simply changing the rule to `foo0 x = foo' x` would make the rule work when inlining reveals the application.

Comment: AFAIK, `foo x = foo' x` is generally not legal in rewrite rules.

Comment: Sure it is. Most of them look like that.

Comment: Interesting! But no, it doesn't seem to do the trick, with `∀ x . foo x = foo' x` the error is about not being able to match `p1 Bool (f1 Bool) -> p1 Char (f1 Char)` with `t`.

Comment: I tracked the problem far enough to come up with a solution, although I don't know *exactly* where the original code goes wrong. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that GHC gets confused somehow. GHC is generally *supposed* to float all `forall`s and class contexts as far left as possible, but it seems that doesn't happen at the right time here. Speculation: this could have something to do with attempts to support the currently-broken `ImpredicativeTypes` extension. We can, however, do it manually, at which point GHC stops complaining about the rule.

Dan Doel tells me that accepting `id` as an implementation of these functions was itself a compiler bug in GHC 7.10, so I'll write them out properly.

```
foo :: (Choice p, Applicative f) => Prism' s a -> p a (f a) -> p s (f s)
foo x = x

-- Avoid a warning about the rule not firing.
{-# INLINE [0] foo #-}

foo' :: (Choice p, Applicative f) => Prism' Char Bool -> p Bool (f Bool) -> p Char (f Char)
foo' x = x

{-# RULES "foo/foo'" foo = foo' #-}
```